# Calling an Nginx Named location more than once

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I seem to have ended up with working code that includes the lines `try_files false @phpfpm;`  This can't be good can it!?

I'm trying to rate limit calls to WordPress login page.  Due to Nginx's (amazingly powerful) location blocks I need two location blocks (I think) and so have used a Named Location Block so I don't have to define all the PHP-FPM stuff more than once.

The issue seems to be that [named location blocks can be reached only via error_page, post_action & try_files](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/community/faq/#what-does-this-thing-mean).  So I have this weird login config.

```
  location @phpfpm {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-sitexxx.sock;
  }

  location ~ ^/(wp-login|wp-comments-post|xmlrpc)\.php$ {
    limit_req zone=perip burst=5 nodelay;
    try_files false @phpfpm;
  }

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    try_files false @phpfpm;
  }
```

Is this OK for production?

I feel I have missed something?

Comment: Have you considered using an `include` directive to move common code into a separate file?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I am using includes many times elsewhere in this configuration.  Are you suggesting I put the `@phpfpm` block in a separate file and then include it twice from the location blocks?  Interesting but I already have over 200 site config files so that would result in over 400 files :-/

Comment: So, does the `limit_req` bit actually work? Because you may end up replicating the fastcgi code across location blocks anyway.

Comment: `limit_req` is working great, in fact the whole config is working great it just feels very clumsy.  By using `try_files false` I am effectively asking Nginx to check for a file called `false` and pass the request to `@phpfpm` only if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I have seen similar hacks using `try_files @phpfpm @phpfpm` which presumably is looking for a file called @phpfpm. I read somewhere that the `error_page 418` approach is considered to be the more efficient technique.